# Erratic Build Error with Legacy VC++/VC# Project - WPP Related

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I am working on a recently inherited Visual Studio 2005 project, made up of a mix of C++ and C#. I am having a strange problem where one computer builds a particular Solution just fine, while attempts on another computer or my colleague's machine (with identical OS, .NET, DDK, Platform SDK, etc) are met with build errors on particular sub-projects in the solution. I have searched high and low for anyone experiencing the same issue but haven't found any advice on the subject.

This is Visual Studio 2005 on Windows XP, .NET 2.0 and 3.5 installed.

All the errors seem related to WPP/tracewpp. Which is odd since WPP tracing is working on all other sub-projects in the Solution, minus only a few. There is a pre-build event to run tracewpp.exe, and the classes all have debugging references to WPP functions.

Here is a sample of the output from a failed build:

```
12>ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp
11>Compiling...
11>ChatChannelMember.cpp
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(172) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp172' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(173) : error C2065: 'TRACE_FLAG_SRUNNER' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(172) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp172': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(188) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp188' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(188) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp188': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(208) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp208' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(208) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp208': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(211) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp211' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(211) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp211': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(237) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp237' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(237) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp237': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(250) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp250' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(250) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp250': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(255) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp255' : undeclared identifier
11>ChatChannel.cpp
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(255) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp255': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(299) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp299' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(299) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp299': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(347) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp347' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(348) : error C2065: 'TRACE_FLAG_SRUNNER_NET' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(347) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp347': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(362) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp362' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(362) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp362': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(390) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp390' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(390) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp390': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(446) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp446' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(446) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp446': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(472) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp472' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(472) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp472': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(494) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp494' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(494) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp494': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(520) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp520' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(520) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp520': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(534) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp534' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(534) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp534': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(553) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp553' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(553) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp553': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(597) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp597' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(597) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp597': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(602) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp602' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(602) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp602': identifier not found
11>chat_log.cpp
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(655) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp655' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(655) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp655': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(693) : warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp693'
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(693) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(694) : warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp694'
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(695) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp695' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(695) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp695': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(704) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp704' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(704) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp704': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(751) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp751' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(751) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp751': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(756) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp756' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(756) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp756': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(771) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp771' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(771) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp771': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(804) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp804' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(804) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp804': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(874) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp874' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(874) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp874': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(956) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp956' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(956) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp956': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(1086) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp1086' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(1086) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp1086': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(1239) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp1239' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(1239) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp1239': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(1309) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp1309' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(1309) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp1309': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(1474) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp1474' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(1474) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp1474': identifier not found
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(1490) : error C2065: 'WPP_ANNOTATE_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp1490' : undeclared identifier
12>.\ServerRunnerNetwork.cpp(1490) : error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_ServerRunnerNetwork_cpp1490': identifier not found
```

Please let me know any other information needed and I will update my answer.

Comment: I'm assuming you have the exact same solution, right (like, the files were copy/pasted onto the other machine)?

Comment: @Rakete1111 yes that is correct, the files were checked out from version control in the exact same state

Comment: Try increasing the log verbosity of the build. This might help pinpoint the exact problem. [Some additional information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx). I hope that 2005 has this option :/

Comment: @Rakete1111 I increased the verbosity to Diagnostic, but sadly the output of and around the error remains the same as above.